# How to recursively enumerate the files in a directory and return relative path instead of absolute path in ASP.net using VB.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

A want to recursive enumerate the files in a directory. If I use

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/"), "*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Function(a) Path.GetFullPath(a))
```

It returns a string list of Absolute Paths starting with the drive letter. I want to get a list of Relative Paths only (Relative to Application Folder).